# How do I compare tuple values?

Tags: scala, tuples

I just have a quick syntax question and I don't find the answer.
I have a tuple, for example (2, 3), and I want to compare those values. For the sake of the question, I boiled it down to one specific case with the problem.

I have tried to do it like this:

```scala
def isNumberOneBigger(tuple: Tuple): Boolean = tuple match {
      case tuple._1 > tuple._2 => true
}
```

It doesn't work. When I used compareTo or similar suggestions, I always got an error. Since my code is a little longer and more complicated, I can't just use if-else. Pattern matching makes a lot of sense.
Does anyone know? It feels so simple but I am new to Scala.

Answer (score 7):

Here's two matching-based solutions:

```
def isNumberOneBigger(tuple: (Int,Int)): Boolean = tuple match {
  case (x1, x2) => x1 > x2
}

def isNumberOneBigger(tuple: (Int,Int)): Boolean = {
  val (x1, x2) = tuple
  x1 > x2
}
```

without matching, it's:

```
def isNumberOneBigger(tuple: (Int,Int)): Boolean =
  tuple._1 > tuple._2
```

which seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue using pattern matching, you could write the following code

```
def isNumberOneBigger(tuple: (Int,Int)): Boolean ={
  tuple match {
    case x: (Int,Int)  if x._1 > x._2 => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
def isNumberOneBigger(tuple: (Int, Int)): Boolean = tuple match {
    case (a: Int, b:Int) if (a > b) => true
    case _ => false
}
```

Pay attention to add `case _` => otherwise, you will get `MatchError` exception.

You can "play" with it a little [here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/wguXkLg/0)